# Number of subsets in arithmetic progression

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S=\{1,2,3...,n\}$. Find the number of subsets of $S$ such that all elements are in arithmetic progression with size of each subset being at least $3$.
I proceeded with the standard recursion stuffs and noticed the pattern that $a_{n+1}-a_{n}-{a_n-1}=d(n+2)-1$ where $d$ is the divisor function and $a_{n}$ is the answer for $n$ but can't prove it rigorously. I would like to see a formal proof and cool solution.

Comment: what is $d$?${}{}$

Comment: That recurrence seems false to me. Why would the divisors of $n+1$ matter? I think the divisors of $n$ make more sense when considering progressions of $\{1,\dots, n+1\}$

Comment: Would you then please take the effort to post a proper solution?

Comment: A proper solution of what?

Comment: You want a formula for that expression, what are the requirements for the formula? what sort of complexity are you aiming for?

Comment: Yeah i want a closed form of the expression